# EBS Storage was upgraded in the AWS console but not in ec2 ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, storage, amazon-ebs

My EBS storage volume for EC2 instance was nearly full then I tried to upgrade from 50gb to 70gb. The upgrade process take a long time, I didn't check how many minute/hours but after some days I see the progress status was completed. Then I tried go to SSH and using command `df -h`, but the size still 50gb.  Why?
[image]

`mount` return :

```
[root@ip-172-31-23-37 ec2-user]# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=1878544k,nr_inodes=469636,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on / type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=25,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=13932)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=379360k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

I tried `xfs_growfs -d /dev/nvme0n1p1` return:

```
[root@ip-172-31-23-37 ec2-user]# xfs_growfs -d /dev/nvme0n1p1
meta-data=/dev/nvme0n1p1         isize=512    agcount=26, agsize=524159 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=13106683, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data size unchanged, skipping
```

without `-d` arg:

```
[root@ip-172-31-23-37 kristacrm-new]# xfs_growfs /dev/nvme0n1p1
meta-data=/dev/nvme0n1p1         isize=512    agcount=26, agsize=524159 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=13106683, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

I also tried `xfs_resize` but command is not found

I tried to reboot my EC2 instance but still 50gb.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your filesystem is `ext4` run:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

That should help :)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it's returned `resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1p1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.`

Comment: maybe my filesystem is XFS. I run `fsck` then return `If you wish to check the consistency of an XFS filesystem or
repair a damaged filesystem, see xfs_repair(8). `

Comment: Post the output of `mount` - it will show the filesystem type. If it’s not `ext4` then it’s probably `xfs` in which case `xfs_resize` should work.

Comment: check my updated question, `xfs_resize` is not found command

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur it’s actually `xfs_growfs` not `xfs_resize`, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Just found  [the AWS official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

first, use the `lsblk` command to display information about the NVMe block devices attached to the instance. :

```
    [root@ip-172-31-23-37 ~]# lsblk
    NAME          MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    nvme0n1       259:0    0  70G  0 disk
    |-nvme0n1p1   259:1    0  50G  0 part /
    `-nvme0n1p128 259:2    0   1M  0 part
    [root@ip-172-31-23-37 ~]# growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
    CHANGED: partition=1 start=4096 old: size=104853471 end=104857567 new: size=146796511 end=146800607
```

`nvme0n1` have 70gb but the `nvme0n1p1`(maybe the partition) only 50gb.

To extend the partition on the root volume, use the following `growpart  /dev/nvme0n1 1` command. Notice that there is a space between the device name and the partition number.

```
[root@ip-172-31-23-37 ~]# growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
CHANGED: partition=1 start=4096 old: size=104853471 end=104857567 new: size=146796511 end=146800607
```

Then check using `lsblk` again :

```
[root@ip-172-31-23-37 ~]# lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1       259:0    0  70G  0 disk
|-nvme0n1p1   259:1    0  70G  0 part /
`-nvme0n1p128 259:2    0   1M  0 part
```

Now `nvme0n1p1` size is same as `nvme0n1`. But the df command still shows 50gb

```
[root@ip-172-31-23-37 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  384K  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1   50G   41G  9.6G  81% /
tmpfs           371M     0  371M   0% /run/user/1000
```

The final command is `xfs_growfs -d /` and will return:

```
[root@ip-172-31-23-37 ~]# xfs_growfs -d /
meta-data=/dev/nvme0n1p1         isize=512    agcount=26, agsize=524159 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=13106683, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 13106683 to 18349563
```

Gotcha!!! Finnaly the `df` command show 70gb too.

```
[root@ip-172-31-23-37 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  384K  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1   70G   41G   30G  58% /
tmpfs           371M     0  371M   0% /run/user/1000
```